# Finding a quantile $\rho=\frac{5}{16}$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I want to find a quantile $\rho=\frac{5}{16}$ of exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$. I understand that i need to find $P(X\ge x_p)\ge 1-\frac{5}{16}$ which is $1-F_X(x_p) \ge 1-\frac{5}{16}$ thus i want to have $F_X(x_p)=\frac{5}{16}$. How to proceed with that? Because i am lost at this point. In the answer booklet i have next step is to find $\frac{5}{16}=1-e^{-\lambda x_p}$ but why? Why not $\frac{5}{16}=1-\lambda e^{-\lambda x_p}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clear the confusion, if $X\sim \exp(λ)$ then $$f(x)=λe^{-λx}$$ for $x>0$ and $$F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^xf(x)dx=1-e^{-λx}$$ for $x>0$ (so there is no $λ$ in front of the exponential in the cdf $F$). So, in this case $$F(x_p)=\frac{5}{16}\implies 1-e^{-λx_p}=\frac5{16}\implies x_p=-\frac1λ\ln(11/16)$$

Comment: I missed the integration part, thank you!